# count rows for particular value from different table both table contains one same column?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
Account(Acc_no, branch_name,balance)
Depositor(cust_name,Acc_no)
```

Find no. of depositors at each branch?

Comment: Please take the time to read this: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . It is easier for use to help when we are able to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.branch_name, COUNT(D.cust_name) FROM Account A INNER JOIN Depositor D GROUP BY A.branch_name
```

Hope this helps

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: See last line of his question "Find no. of depositors at each branch"

Comment: That's weird. I was working through the Review Queue and your answer showed up as the question...

Comment: Haha, may be some bug with their app

Comment: got it  SELECT ACCOUNT.BRANCH_NAME, COUNT(DEPOSITOR.CUST_NAME) FROM ACCOUNT  INNER JOIN Depositor ON ACCOUNT.ACC_NO=DEPOSITOR.ACC_NO GROUP BY BRANCH_NAME;

Answer (score 0):

SELECT ACCOUNT.BRANCH_NAME, COUNT(DEPOSITOR.CUST_NAME) FROM ACCOUNT  INNER JOIN Depositor ON ACCOUNT.ACC_NO=DEPOSITOR.ACC_NO GROUP BY BRANCH_NAME;